# PL/SQL insufficient privileges within a query manually possible

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to do this task, and update this table that has a lot of rows.

This table has 2 columns:

**FOO** and **BAR**

I have FOO as PK and I know those values, they are both numbers but I don't have any value at bar.

I can manually run every query without any problems, but I made this PL/SQL so it automatically run without any problem, once I need to find the BAR value within another query.

```
create or replace procedure FxB_pro
IS
  tmpFIELD NUMBER := 0; 
  i NUMBER := 0;
  cursor c1 is  
    SELECT * FROM FooXBar WHERE BAR IS NULL;
BEGIN

  FOR CTUpdate IN c1
  LOOP 
    BEGIN
      SELECT t5.bar INTO tmpFIELD FROM table_1 t1, table_2 t2, table_3 t3, table_4 t4, table_5 t5, table_6 t6
      where t1.fielda_id = t2.fielda_id
      and t2.fielda_id = t3.fielda_id
      and t3.fieldb_id = t4.fieldb_id 
      and t3.fieldb_id = t6.fieldb_id
      and t4.fieldd_id = t5.fieldc_id
      and t1.fieldc = CTUpdate.FOO
      and rownum = 1;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        tmpFIELD :=null;
    END;

    UPDATE FooXBar set BAR = tmpFIELD where FOO=CTUpdate.FOO;

    i := i+1;

    IF mod(i, 1000) = 0 THEN    -- Commit every 1000 records
      COMMIT;
    END IF;

  END LOOP; 
  COMMIT;
END;
```

I've tested this in my properly **Test Environment** the PL/SQL Is created and runs, but when I'm going to run it in Production, I have this error in the Select which put the value in **tmpFIELD**:

```
Erro(12,11): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Erro(12,143): PL/SQL: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

I can't figure why this is happening, can someone please help me?

Comment: The error is pretty clear - you don't have privileges in the Production environment - you don't have the authority to read those tables (I assume; there is no "privilege" to assign to a local variable). Note that by default, the privileges are those of the "definer" (the user who created the procedure); you can also make the procedure run with invoker's privileges, if that's what you need - you can read about it all in the documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21901_01/timesten.1122/e21639/accesscntl.htm#TTPLS273

Comment: Even when i'm using adm user in DB and can run the query individually? I See now, thanks. I'm going to search through this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your privileges are assigned via ROLE.
This is fine with direct SQL, but don't work with PL/SQL.

You need to acquire the privileges direct to you user.

While testing the PL/SQL queries set in advance

```
 set role none;
```

this will deactivate the priviledges acquired via `ROLE` and show possible problems running in PL/SQL.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know the role doesn't work with PL/SQL .

Comment: You can use roles as well, but then you need the role `WITH GRANT OPTION`. That actually makes sense, since the procedure accesses the table, but you can grant access to the procedure to other users, therefore giving them indirect access to the table.